# How to clear cache of Windows 8.1 WebView from code?

Tags: c#, webview, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I am developing a webview based app for a client. It's basically a kiosk app. One can configure which website will be in webview. Now when the website is updated, the changes are not reflected in website. webview uses the cached version of website. Googling the problem leads to me the conculution that, I need to delete the content of `INetCache` folder from `%localappdata%\Packages\PACKAGE_ID_OF_APP\AC`. I know to access this folder in WinRT is not possible. So any one has idea how to clear cache?

I think using powershell I can delete the folder. My app is not going to publish in the store. App is sideloaded using enterprise key. So invoking powershell scripts is possible from WinRT apps?

Answer (score 0):

the powershell command Remove-item deletes a file or folder. To prevent it from prompting it to confirm the delete, add -recurse at the emd.

```
Remove-Item c:\appdata\local\microsoft\windows\inetcache -recurse
```

[Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176938.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I invoke this command from WinRT app?

Comment: @Xyroid Powershell seems to be disabled directly from WinRT apps. The only solution would be to maybe use WinRT socket support to either connect to a PowerShell Web Access port or a PowerShell remoting endpoint

Comment: A side-loaded app can use a Brokered Windows Runtime Component to bypass the sandbox and call desktop code. There's a whitepaper with details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn630195.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know this solution is not "From Code" although I just spent half the day attempting to resolve this issue via Visual Studio. I Hope this saves someone some time and headache.

In my current version of Visual Studio 2015 CTP I was also struggling with somewhat the same issue. I was debugging js and the Webview facade would not reload the new js file for debugging purposes. To force it to do this there is a setting in Solution->Properties->Debug-> check the box `"Uninstall and then re install my package. All information about the application state is deleted"`. Do this then perform the following steps:

```
1.Build -> Clean
2.Build -> Rebuild Solution
3.Build -> Deploy Solution
4.Finally F5 re run your test on the remote machine.
```

Hopefully your JavaScript files when loaded into the Webview session will reflect your changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the equivalent of `<CTRL + F5>` by injecting some Javascript:

`MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "location.reload(true)" });`

Passing `true` bypasses the cache. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload).